# Параллельный (потокобезопасный) ассоциативный контейнер для строк(std::string)

Tags: stl, c++

Нужен параллельный(потоко-безопасный) ассоциативный контейнер для строк(`std::string`).

Используется в 2 потоках. 
В 1 потоке пишется(`operator[]`)
во 2 читается(`count()>0` и затем `operator[]`).

- Никакие другие другие операции в обоих потоках над ним не выполняются.
- Вставка нового элемента (с уникальным ключём) осуществляется только 1 раз, дальше только считывается.
- Порядок вставки значения не имеет.
- Желательно чтобы это было в STL или boost(что то очень крупное подключать не хочется).

Аналог:
`std::map` или `std::unordered_map`

Есть ли что нибудь в PPL?
Или проще ставить мьютексы?

Comment: concurrent_vector?

Comment: @Flammable: Это микрософтовский или из TBB?

Comment: @VladD, это PLL и это гуглится.

Comment: @Flammable: чё-то у меня "pll gcc" не гуглится. А с Visual Studio, да, идёт, но он, судя по всему, микрософтовский.

Comment: @VladD, автор спрашивал про PLL, я предложил вариант из PLL.

Comment: @manking, IMHO [здесь в SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067160/stdmap-thread-safety) утверждают (со ссылками на стандарты), что сам по себе контейнер std::map потокобезопасен, только вот это потокобезопасность не в смысле Вашей задачи (логической согласованности действий 2-х потоков), а безопасность в смысле, что структура не разрушится (программа не упадет) при попытке одновременного изменения контейнера (естественно, это не относится к erase и итераторам).

Comment: @avp: хм, интересная ссылка. Но там, если я правильно понимаю, не модификация контейнера, а модификация элемента _в контейнере_.

Comment: Понял.

Ассоциативный контейнер не фиксированного размера,  с шаблонным ключом, предоставляющий возможность запрашивать информацию о своей внутренней структуре и осуществлять над ней операции из нескольких потоков невозможен даже в теории.

Чтобы работать с таким контейнером из разных потоков, нужно либо выполнять синхронизацию действий, либо другой поток должен работать с копией(вроде передачи само уничтожающихся умных указателей),все остальные действия могут приводить к получению некорректных результатов или испортить сам контейнер. Или можно проектировать логику изначально потокобезопасной

Comment: @VladD, согласен. Тем более [в другом месте SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130494/are-stdmap-and-stdvector-thread-safe) явно пишут 

    but not container!

Странные люди, эти разработчики крестов. Снявши голову (ведь все  через копирование (а как иначе обеспечить целостность в общем случае?)), по волосам (pthread_mutex... на весь контейнер) плачут...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Единственный правильный путь — вставить свою синхронизацию.

Никакой контейнер не знает, что именно вы подразумеваете под потокобезопасностью. Потокобезопасность — свойство не контейнера, а вашего кода. Подумайте, как может выглядеть потокобезопасный вариант функции `count`? Чтобы вот такой код работал:

```
if (container.count() > 0)
    x = container[0];
```

(Подсказка: никак.)

Comment: Понятно. А как называется, когда один поток должен считывать какие то данные которые изменяются в другом потоке? 

Например 1й поток постоянно изменяет `std::map<std::string , int> names`.

2й поток раз в 2 минуты хочет знать, что находится в контейнере names с ключом "123".


Это значит не правильная "архитектура" и нужно менять саму логику работы, или есть конкретные методы как так работать(с удобным контейнером)?

Comment: @manking: ну, архитектура вроде бы нормальная. Хотя наверное лучше рассуждать не на уровне потоков, а на [более высоком](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/future) уровне.

Потокобезопасность — это свойство программы «правильно» себя вести в присутствии одновременного доступа к данным из разных потоков. Что означает «правильно» — определяется архитектором программы, то есть вами.

Для вашего случая (один writer и один reader) вполне достаточно одного mutex'а вокруг операций чтения/модификации.